# Same exit node (that change) for two different site

Tags: exit-relays

To use same exit node for two different site i can use in torrc:

```
AllowDotExit 1
MapAddress site1.com site1.nodeA.exit
MapAddress site2.com site2.nodeA.exit
```

But in this way i use always the same exit node for site1 and site2.

I want to use the same exit node for site1 and site2, but the exit node must change like other exit node. For example, if in tor browser i use "New Tor Circuit for this Site" when i am on site1 and then go to site2, the new exit node used on site1 must be the same on site2.
Is this possible?

Comment: No, this isn't possible without you creating some tool to actively reconfigure Tor through the control port.